# How to AsyncTask to Fragments from onPageSelected of ViewPager?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-viewpager

I'm new to Android programming.
I googled & stackoverflowed, read android docs but nothing helped me or maybe I didn't understand well.

I'm trying to AsyncTask UI to fragment via onPageSelected from ViewPager.

Like AndroMoney app ViewPager(Before onPageSelected, it shows "loading...", when onPageSelected, it AsyncTasked and loaded.):

[AndroMoney ViewPager Fragment Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGCUz.png)

but my code is: it asynctasked while swipping and sometimes it stops between two fragments like this:

[my code viewpager screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5lfZ.png)

unlike AndroMoney app, my code doesn't asynctask onPageSelected.

here is MyFragment.java:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "EXTRA_MESSAGE";
    final StringBuilder buffer=new StringBuilder();
    View v;
    public static final MyFragment newInstance(int message) {
        MyFragment f = new MyFragment();
        Bundle bdl = new Bundle(1);
        bdl.putInt(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        f.setArguments(bdl);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfragment_layout, container, false);
        new AsyncDatabase().execute();
        return v;
    }

    public class AsyncDatabase extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){
            int message = getArguments().getInt(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
            BibleService bService=new BibleServiceImpl(getActivity().getApplication());
            List<Bible> bible=bService.getBibleByChapterNumber("Salm", message);
            for(Bible b: bible){
                for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                    buffer.append(b);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
            TextView txt1=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            TextView txt2=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            txt1.setText("Done");
            txt2.setText(buffer.toString());
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            TextView txt1=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            txt1.setText("Loading...");
        }
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values){

        }
    }


}
```

here is PageViewActivity.java:

```
public class PageViewActivity extends FragmentActivity{
    MyPageAdapter pageAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_page_view);

        List<Fragment> fragments = getFragments();

        pageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
        pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
        pager.setCurrentItem(11);

        pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }

            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
                    int positionOffsetPixels) {
            }

            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            }
        });

    }

    private List<Fragment> getFragments() {
        List<Fragment> fList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

        for (int j = 2; j < 150; j++) {
            fList.add(MyFragment.newInstance(j));
        }

        return fList;
    }

    private class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        private List<Fragment> fragments;

        public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
            super(fm);
            this.fragments = fragments;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return this.fragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return this.fragments.size();
        }

    }
```

I tested stupidly by adding the following code:

```
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                new MyFragment().new AsyncDatabase().execute();
            }
```

It didn't work.:-P

So, how to asynctask to fragment from onPageSelected of PageViewActivity like AndroMoney app.

Answer (score 0):

Expose a new method in your fragment:

```
public void executeAsyncTask() {
   new AsyncDatabase().execute();
}
```

In the activity, make your list of fragments final, so you can access it in the Adapter:

```
final List<MyFragment> fragments = getFragments();
```

Then change your onPageSelected() method to be:

```
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    fragments.get(position).executeAsyncTask();
}
```

You'll also need to update the MyPagerAdapter to use MyFragment instead of Fragment:

```
private class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private List<MyFragment> fragments;

    public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<MyFragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return this.fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }

}

private List<MyFragment> getFragments() {
    List<MyFragment> fList = new ArrayList<MyFragment>();

    for (int j = 2; j < 150; j++) {
        fList.add(MyFragment.newInstance(j));
    }

    return fList;
}
```